Yii2 has option to enable custom error handling, but is there option to enable custom exception handling?
Yii2 documents custom error handling here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-handling-errors and it separates error handling from exception handling:

@yii/views/errorHandler/error.php: used when errors should be displayed WITHOUT call stack information. When YII_DEBUG is false, this is the only error view to be displayed.
@yii/views/errorHandler/exception.php: used when errors should be displayed WITH call stack information.


But this is unclear - the text suggests, that error.php is for production environment and exception.php is for the development/debug environment.
The furhter suggestion about approach of:
return [
    'components' => [
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
    ]
];

does not take into account this difference.
My SiteController has code:
public function actionError()
{
    error_log('actionError happens!');

    $exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;
    if ($exception instanceof \yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException) {
        Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 401;

        $data = new \stdClass();
        $data->error = true;
        $data->message = $exception->getMessage();
        return json_encode($data);
    }

    $data = new \stdClass();
    $data->error = true;
    $data->message = 'An internal error occurred.';
    return json_encode($data);
}

that registers the execution (via error_log) and that outputs the error in the technical format only, but there are cases, when this error handling is bypassed and still the @yii/views/errorHandler/exception.php is used by Yii2 for reporting the error.
Almost always all the serious exceptions are reported in this way, e.g.
Throwable... Undefined property: stdClass::$sal_tax
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

are reported in this generic way.
I would prefer my own custom error handling - with the possible registration of the error situation and output in the technical format (so, that my browser side app or mobile side app can do something meaningful about it), but I can not find, how to override the in-built exception handling in these more serious situations. And they can happen - PHP is not type checked.

Yii2 errorHandler (both yii\web\ErrorHandler and yii\console\ErrorHandler) is a wrapper for all types of error. If you look at the hierarchy of PHP errors and exceptions, then catching throwable ensures that any kind of error is handled by aforementioned errorHandler. This allows routing of an error to any controller/action/view (or you can even extend errorHandler object) and implement your own custom logic to handle it:
$exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception
$code = $exception->getCode();

if ($code == E_PARSE) {
   // handle parse errors
} elseif ($code == 404) {
   // handle page not found exceptions
} else {
   // ...
}

Note that all PHP errors are converted into exception object and you can use either $exception->code or $exception->severity to determine error type. See also PHP error codes.
